# Why am I getting NameError: name 'ActionChains' is not defined?

Tags: python

Im pretty new to python and trying to fill out a web form automated.

Im getting this Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 24, in 
>       ActionChains(browser)\
>   NameError: name 'ActionChains' is not defined

And this is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome ('/Users/max/Downloads/chromedriver')

browser.get ('http://www.brix.de/computer/web_html_php_et_al/formular-test_smm_01.html')

inputs = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/form[1]/table')

ActionChains(browser)\
.move_to_element(input[vorname]).click()\
.send_keys('name')\
.move_to_element(input[name]).click()\
.send_keys('Surname')\
.perform()
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: You are missing the import for `ActionChains`, [see here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are missing the import, try the following:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome ('/Users/kiran/Downloads/chromedriver')

browser.get ('http://www.brix.de/computer/web_html_php_et_al/formular-test_smm_01.html')

inputs = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/form[1]/table')

ActionChains(browser)\
.move_to_element(input[name]).click()\
.send_keys('name')\
.move_to_element(input[vorname]).click()\
.send_keys('Surname')\
.perform()
```

Comment: how to know the module name? The selenium official documentation https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/ doesn't provide this module/package path name (selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) for python, java, ruby or all languages and it's unguessable